# python interpreter selection not showed in status bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open a directory containing python files using vscode, I can't select which interpreter I am using through the statusbar as it should  as showed on the attached figure.

[image]

Digging a bit further, it seems that the python extensions that I use are not activated for this project but I do not known how this happened. The extensions I am using are Python/Intellisense, Pylint, Pylance. I tried to unsintall/reinstall those extensions but the problem persists. Would you know how to solve this problem ?

```
Info:
Version: 1.67.2
Commit: c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5
Date: 2022-05-17T18:23:40.286Z
Electron: 17.4.1
Chromium: 98.0.4758.141
Node.js: 16.13.0
V8: 9.8.177.13-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.13.0-44-generic snap
```

Comment: you have to use the command **Python: Select Interpreter** once to get the status bar selector

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. How to run that command ? When I do a Ctrl+Shift+P, it is not proposed to me.

Comment: adjusted the command, if not available then the Python extension is not enabled, enable it from the extension page

Comment: it is enabled, that's what puzzles me.

Comment: what if you disable all but the Python extension

Comment: That what I just tried. I disabled Python and Jupyter and it seems to be OK. Very strange. Thanks for your help.

Comment: then enable one by one and see which is the culprit and not working as expected